# custom permission for widget broadcast receiver

Tags: android, permissions, widget, broadcastreceiver

I know that we can add custom permissions while sending the broadcast and check for the same in `onReceive()` method in the receiver.

I set`PendingIntent pendingIntent` on the UI elements so they will be fired. How do we add these permissions in the widget, as we dont explicitly send broadcasts.

**CODE**

```
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   if(intent.getAction() == Constants.UPDATE){
    //Do refresh operations here

    }


//Setting UI actions
private static void setActionIntent(Context context, RemoteViews views,
            int id, String action) {
        Intent i = new Intent(action);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(id, pendingIntent );
    }
```

Comment: Because I set pending intents on UI elements, they will auto fire the intents when user clicks on these elements.

Comment: Did you register the receiver?

Comment: I register the receiver in AndroidManifest.xml If its a normal broadcast, I would use "To enforce a permission when sending, you supply a non-null permission argument to sendBroadcast(Intent, String)" and check for the permission in the receiver. But here, how do I send the broadcast with permission as its pendingIntent. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html